# Как соеденить две таблицы через ключ в django queryset

Tags: python, django

Есть две таблички c FK в одной из них.

родитель:

```
+----+---------+
| Id |  Name   |
+----+---------+
|  1 | Test #1 |
|  2 | Test #2 |
|  3 | Test #3 |
+----+---------+
```

дочерняя:

```
+----+---------+-----------+
| Id | Traffic | parent_id |
+----+---------+-----------+
|  1 |    1000 |         1 |
|  2 |    2000 |         3 |
+----+---------+-----------+
```

Мне нужно сделать queryset для формы и соеденить их по ключу. На sql что то аналогичное запросу:

```
select p.parent_id, p.traffic, c.name from child c, parent p where c.parent_id = p.id
```

Форма:

```
class NewForm(forms.Form):
    query = Child.objects.all()....

    selectbox = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=query,
                                       required=True,
                                       initial=0,
                                       widget=forms.Select,
                                       label=_(u'Select field'))
    class Meta:
        fields = [
            'selectbox',
        ]
```

Есть какой то простой путь для этого?

Comment: Нашел что квери можно оформить таким образом: query = Child.objects.all().values_list('id', 'parent__name'). Это даёт два необходимых поля, но вот вывод на шаблон получается не таким, как нужно. Выдаёт "option value="(1L, u'Test #1')">(1L, u'Test #1')</option", вместо "option value="1">Test #1</option". Как получить нормальный результат еще не нашел.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вобщем получилось найти вот такое решение (спасибо народу с pyha forum)

```
def get_server_list():
    return Child.objects.all().values_list('parent_id',
                                           'parent__name')

class NewForm(forms.Form):
    selectbox = forms.Field(required=True,
                            widget=forms.Select,
                            label=_(u'Select field'))

    class Meta:
        fields = [
            'selectbox',
        ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('label_suffix', '')
        super(NewForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['selectbox'] = \
            forms.ChoiceField(choices=
                              [(o[0], str(o[1])) for o in get_server_list()],
                              initial=1
                              )
```

Теперь можно использовать поле selectbox в шаблоне, как:

```
{% render_field form.selectbox class="form-control required" %}
```

и получить вменяемый код выбора на странице:

```
<select class="form-control required" name="selectbox">
  <option value="1">Test #1</option>
  <option value="3">Test #3</option>
</select>
```

Не уверен что это оптимальный путь, но во всяком случае работает как мне нужно.